# Graded monoids: What does it mean to say a monoid is graded by another monoid?

Tags: category-theory, computer-science, monoid, lambda-calculus, monads

The question https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/129236/creating-a-large-tuple-from-smaller-tuples-via-a-monad-or-applicative/129482#129482
regards the existence of a procedure which uses a monad for assembling tuples in the lambda calculus whose components are of possibly different type.

According to the only answer given, a tuple could be constructed using the graded monoid of finite sequences, if the tuple contained expressions of the same type. My first question is the following:

- What is the graded monoid of finite sequences?

For the case in which a tuple contains expressions of different type it is claimed that:

> In theory we could have used any monoid graded by any other monoid, (for example the monoid of heterogeneous lists, graded by the monoid of lists of types -- if we wanted to be able to talk about heterogeneous tuples)the monoid of heterogeneous lists, graded by the monoid of lists of types.

- What does it mean to say a monoid is *graded* by another monoid? I can find discussions of graded monoids in the literature but not a clear explanation of what it means to say a monoid is *graded* by another monoid
- What exactly is the monoid of heterogeneous lists graded by the monoid of lists of types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a general description of graded objects, but for the purposes of just defining graded monoids it's possible to simplify:

> A *grading* of a monoid $M$ by another monoid $N$ is just a homomorphism $\varphi : M \to N$. The preimages $\varphi^{-1}(n)$ are the *graded components* $M_n$ of $M$; the elements of $M_n$ are said to be of *degree* or *grade* $n$.

As a simple example, the monoid $\mathbb{N}^k$ is graded by $\mathbb{N}$ with the grading given by taking the sum of the components. Taking the [monoid ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_ring) of this example produces the familiar grading of multivariate polynomials by total degree, although we need a somewhat different definition of what a grading of a ring is.

---

I don't quite know what "heterogeneous lists" means, but I can make a guess. Suppose you have a collection of types $T_i, i \in I$ indexed by a set $I$. Then you can construct the monoid of lists of elements where each element can be in any of the types $T_i$; equivalently, the monoid of lists of elements of the [sum type](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sum+type) $\coprod_i T_i$. This monoid admits a grading, which remember is just a homomorphism, by the monoid of lists of elements of $I$; this homomorphism is determined by sending each element to its type.

For example, suppose we have two types, `string`s and `int`s. A heterogenous list of `string`s and `int`s looks like

> `{"dog", 3, "mouse", "cat", 7, ...}`

and the corresponding list of types is

> `{string, int, string, string, int, ...}`